# Jenkins - stop jobs automatically building after organization scan

Tags: jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am automatically adding a GitHub Organization to my Jenkins instance when it starts up, but when it adds each job it executes it.  This causes many many jobs to be executed, clogging up the build queue for a long time (hours).  Is there a way to import each project through the Jenkinsfile, but not automatically run the build?

I am running the following code when I startup the Jenkins instance:

```
import jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.BranchDiscoveryTrait
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMNavigator
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.OriginPullRequestDiscoveryTrait
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubConfiguration

import static jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance as jenkins

static Boolean organisationFolderExists(String name) {
    def folders = jenkins.items
    if (folders.isEmpty()) {
        return false
    }

    def organisation = folders.find { folder -> folder.name == name }

    return organisation
}

String lookupApiUri(def apiEndpoint) {
    GitHubConfiguration gitHubConfig = GitHubConfiguration.get()
    gitHubConfig.getEndpoints().findResult { it.name == apiEndpoint ? it.apiUri : null }
}

void createOrganisationFolder(def config) {
    def folder = jenkins.createProject(OrganizationFolder, config.name)
    folder.displayName = config.displayName
    folder.description = config.description

    GitHubSCMNavigator navigator = new GitHubSCMNavigator(config.name)

    navigator.credentialsId = config.project.scanCredentials
    navigator.apiUri = lookupApiUri(config.project.apiEndpoint)
    navigator.traits = [
        new jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMSourceFilterTrait(config.project.repositoryNamePattern, ''),
        new jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait('.*'),
        new BranchDiscoveryTrait(3),
        new OriginPullRequestDiscoveryTrait(3),
    ]
    folder.navigators.replace(navigator)
    jenkins.save()

    folder.scheduleBuild(0)
}

if (!organisationFolderExists(config.name)) {
    createOrganisationFolder(config)
}
```

This successfully creates the Organization, but I need a way to stop each build executing.  This is connecting to our internal GitHub Enterprise instance.